# how to match this type of construction?

Tags: php, html, parsing, pattern-matching

im doing parsing and the kind of text that i want to match and then make it null is as follows :-

```
<tr class="label-BGC"><td colspan="4">any kind of text here</td></tr>
```

i want to match every line that contains  `"<tr class="label-BGC"><td colspan="4">any text</td></tr>"`

its evening here and my brain-battery is totally down

what im trying to do is :-

```
$patterns='<td colspan="4">'.stristr($parsed,'[^a-z0-9_- $]').'</td></tr>';
$replacements=' ';
$parsed = str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $parsed);
```

$parsed is containing the whole data that im parsing.

my code is not working can anyone help me with some suggestions here!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something simple like this:

```
$parsed = preg_replace('{<tr class="label-BGC"><td colspan="4">.*?</td></tr>}', 
                      $replacements, $parsed);
```

The . matches any character, the * makes it match 0-many, and the ? stops it being greedy -i.e. it will stop at the first  sequence, and not the last possible one.

Comment: Since when does str_replace parse regular expressions?

Comment: str_replace() doesn't support regular expressions, shouldn't you use preg_replace() instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
preg_replace("`\s*<tr\s+class\s*=\s*"label-BGC"\s*>\s*<td\s+colspan\s*=\s*"4"\s*>.*?</td\s*>\s*</tr\s*>\s*`i", "", $content);
```

All the `\s` matching might be a little overkill, but it's very forgiving if this input is coming from a user.

Otherwise, you can probably just get away with

```
preg_replace("`<tr class="label-BGC"><td colspan="4">.*?</td></tr>`i", "", $content);
```